# find the shortest path that uses at most k arcs special

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a graph with nonegative weights, in this graph there are any "special" arcs.
Find an algorithm that can find the minimum path between two vertices s e t, using at most k "special" arcs.
Input: graph, s ,t, k.

I thought about using a tree rooted in s that arrives in t, if there is a path with more than k arcs special scrap.
At this point I should have a DAG and use any algorithm to find the minimum distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two approaches:

1st approach: 
For each vertex `u`, compute `k+1`shortest paths from the source `s` to that vertex. So each vertex will have an array `dst = {d0, d2, d3, .... , dk}` where `di` is the shortest path from `s` to `u` using exactly`i` special arcs.
Now you can use a variation of [dikstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to solve this problem where instead of having one priority queue, you have `k + 1` priority queues where each one corresponds to a value of `i : 0 <= i <= k`.

2nd approach (more elegant):
imagine you have a building that has `k + 1` floors. Each floor has a copy of the graph; however, the special arcs act as stairs between adjacent floors. So if you have a special arc between vertex `u` vertex `v` in the original graph, you will have an arc between each vertex`u` in floor `j (0 <= j <= k-1)` and each vertex `v` in floor `j + 1`. So in this new graph, any path from vertex `u` in floor`0`to vertex`v`in floor `j`uses exactly `j` special arcs. Then in the new graph, you cannot go from any vertex `u` to any other vertex`v`using more than`k`special arcs since you can only climb at most k floors. You can use Dikstra's algorithm to solve the problem on the new graph starting with the source vertex in floor`0`.

The running time is `O(k * |E|  + k * |V| * log(k*|V|))`.